# "The specified network password is not correct" on a certificate without a password, on live server only

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, x509, kentor-authservices

I'm using kentor authservices in a SAML service provider project built in asp webforms.

It works great on the development machine but when I put it on the production server (windows 2012 R2, IIS 8), the X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromFile
call throws an exception "The specified network password is not correct."

Only, the certificate (pfx) has no password and the location it sits in is not secured in any unusual way that I can see, but to be sure i've tried with 'everyone' temporarily granted full access to the folder.

The section of the web config relevant is:

```
<serviceCertificates>
  <add fileName="~/App_Data/M_SSO_SP.pfx"/>
</serviceCertificates>
```

Though I don't think it is code related, based on it working fine on the development machine - possibly some server-side problem with the certificate?

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like getting this error when loading a certificate from file is a known error: [ASP.NET - The specified network password is not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286110/asp-net-the-specified-network-password-is-not-correct/8291956#8291956)

Kentor.AuthServices doesn't set the `MachineKeySet` flag as suggested, which it probably should. I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/issues/457) in the github repo that it should be fixed. Please follow up on that issue to see when a fix is avilable.

Comment: Great, thanks Anders! I did see the comment post on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286110/asp-net-the-specified-network-password-is-not-correct - is it possible to do this without 'filling up the disk' as the comment implies?

Comment: I didn't know of that filling up the disk risk. The [stubidp](http://stubidp.kentor.se) runs on Azure and loads the cert with the `MachineKeySet` flag and I've not seen any issues in the years it's been online.

Comment: Ah ok, it's probably fine then, none of the other posts i've seen about the machinekeyset mention it. Thanks!

Comment: It seems this exact issue is now affecting the Core sample Startup class - `options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("Sustainsys.Saml2.Tests.pfx"));` in \Samples\SampleAspNetCore2ApplicationNETFramework\Startup.cs - I had to change it to `options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("Sustainsys.Saml2.Tests.pfx", "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet));`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, problem solved after I installed my pfx file on server.

Comment: try this: leave the password blank and press enter while installing

Comment: It appears our Windows Server version was the issue. Installing in a newer version of Windows Server (WS 2019) worked. Windows Server 2008 or 2012 does not work.