# Http Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core 7 - Abp.io

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hosting, abp

I am deploying Abp.io project that used .Net core 7 and Angualr to smarterasp.net, but I got this error

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

and I checked the Log file and I found this error

> Host terminated unexpectedly! Volo.Abp.AbpInitializationException: An
> error occurred during ConfigureServicesAsync phase of the module
> Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.AbpOpenIddictAspNetCoreModule,
> Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.AspNetCore, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null. See the inner exception for details.  --->
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The specified
> network password is not correct.

Also, I tried to deploy the same project files to my local IIS and it's working fine.

could you please advise to fix this issue.

Comment: The error message is very specific. Your deployed application cannot start because a provided password that is used during the ConfigureServicesAsync section of your startup is invalid. There is nothing that the community can do. _YOU_ will need to debug your application and review the configuration to understand why it is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: [Does the suggestion useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8291956/7687666)

Comment: @JasonPan No, the issue that I face is the deployment working fine in local IIS but once I publish it online I got this error. Also I don't use X509Certificate2 in the whole project